# Консольный ввод в Java

Tags: java

Я вот читаю сейчас Шильдта, и там про консольный ввод очень мало написано и непонятно. Кто может подсказать мне как будет Java-версия этой программы C++:

```
cin >> string str;
Cout << str;
```

Cout я знаю, system.out.println(str); а как cin будет? Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не всё так просто в мире java:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String str = reader.readLine();

// Пример получения числа
Integer intSample = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

System.out.print(str);
```

А вообще это всё находится в гугле первой же строкой.

Answer (score 2):

```
//считываем 
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
int value=scanner.nextInt(); 
//выводим 
System.out.println(value);
```